# How to return sum from different column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table with the number of goods delivered to a particular person on different dates.

How can I make a (pivot) table to sum the total number of goods delivered on a given date?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, just check the 1st comment below my post,, OP has endorsed that has used Method 2 and is working,, and his followup question has DATEs with blanks , this OP want to fixed [check his link](https://paste.pics/96YGE),, and EDITED part of my post has solved it. The current screen shot is a part of the question !!

Comment: @RajeshS: I can't see how your comment answer my question in any context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Method `1` and `2` are based on the screen shot attached with the question, where Date column no space*

**Method 1 (Pivot Table):**

[image]

- Select `A31:D40.`
- From **I**nsert TAB hit **P**ivot Table & Pivot Chart Wizar.
- Select **M**ultiple Consolidation Option and Pivot Table.
- Hit **N**ext.
- Select **S**imple Page Field For Me and move **N**ext.
- Now select `A30:B40` & hit **A**DD button.
- Next select `C30:D40` and **A**DD it also.
- Then select either **N**ew Worksheet or **E**xisting Sheet option and hit **F**inish button.

---

**Method 2:**

*It comprises Unique Date list and get the SUM for respective Dates.*

[image]

- Formula in cell F101:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF($F$100:F100,$A$101:$A$110)=0), $A$101:$A$110), LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF($F$100:F100, $C$101:$C$110)=0), $C$101:$C$110)),"")
  ```
- Formula in cell G101:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((A$101:A$110=F101)*(B$101:B$110)+(C$101:C$110=F101)*(D$101:D$110))
  ```

**N.B.**

*Method 2 is much better and similar as the attached screen shot.*

---

**::Edited::**

**Caveat**

*This part addresses the recent query by the OP through comments just below this post, has [screen shot link](https://paste.pics/96YGE) also.*

*Since OP has added a new data set has blank rows between Dates, therefore the `Method 2` doesn't works properly.*

- This set of formula need to be used in case data set has few blank rows in Date columns.

[image]

- Formula in cell `H116`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($H$115:H115,$A$116:$A$125)=0)*($A$116:$A$125<>"")), $A$116:$A$125), LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($H$115:H115, $C$116:$C$125)=0)*($C$116:$C$125<>"")), $C$116:$C$125)),LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($H$115:H115, $E$116:$E$125)=0)*($E$116:$E$125<>"")), $E$116:$E$125)),"")
  ```
- Formula in cell `I116`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((A$116:A$125=H116)*($B$116:$B$125<>"")*(B$116:B$125)+(C$116:C$125=H116)*($D$116:$D$125<>"")*(D$116:D$125)+(E$116:E$125=H116)*($F$116:$F$125<>"")*(F$116:F$125))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you @rajesh-s so much for your answer.
I tried Method 2 and it seem to work. But I have a followup question:

I change the scenario where there is a third delivery date but not everyone get 2nd and 3rd delivery.

https://paste.pics/96YGE

I follow your formula, but some cells return incorrect amount.

Comment: https://paste.pics/96YK7



Formula in cell I2: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($I$1:I2,$B$2:$B$12)=0),$B$2:$B$12),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($I$1:I2,$D$2:$D$12)=0),$D$2:$D$12)),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($I$1:I2,$F$2:$F$12)=0),$F$2:$F$12)),"")`



Formula in cell J2: 
`=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$12=I2)*(C$2:C$12)+(D$2:D$12=I2)*(E$2:E$12))+($F$2:$F$12=I2)*($G$2:$G$12)`

Comment: @DonnaFeliciano,, now check the Edited part of my post , has new set of formula, handles blank between properly. I'm sure this solves the issue. If U also find so then [You may accept it as Answer](https://superuser.com/tour) and Up vote also☺

Comment: Y this has been down voted ,, since I've shown all possible methods,, Pivot Table, Dates without blank and finally Dates with blanks,,, with new formula and the screen shot,, plzz write your concern !!

Comment: Wow! You're a legend. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DonnaFeliciano, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺